# Discord shows wrong colors in Unity

Tags: colors, unity

I'm using Linux Mint 20 XFCE if that helps (I've used a Ubuntu 16.04 system before with Unity and the same happened)

Discord is showing odd colors on text/images etc... Here's an example https://i.stack.imgur.com/AnKeO.jpg on the left is shown what Discord showed, on the right is the correctly coloured image.

I've tried changing the color profile but it hasn't worked and no applications are showing this problem, just Discord. (Edit: All chromium programs have the same problem)

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution so I'm posting an answer to help anyone who finds my post.

It was actually a wrong color setting, I went to the settings and color then set my profile to D65 and restarted Discord it now shows colors correctly.

I don't know if D65 will fix anyone else's but it fixed mine, just try all of the profiles.